# Regex not fitting with C#

Tags: c#, regex

I wrote simple program for getting info from web

```
string loginName = null;
Regex rloginName = new Regex(@" <tr><td dir='rtl'><h1>(.*?)</h1><br /></td></tr> <!--.............. Titel der Referat ..............-->");

Match mloginName = rloginName.Match(source);
if (mloginName.Success)
{

}
```

ok i test this on RegexBuddy 3 every thing is fine but in my code cant get something too return ,

so where is my code problem

here is code :

```
<tr><td dir='rtl'><h1>xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx@xxx.xxx</h1><br /></td></tr> <!--.............. Titel der Referat ..............-->     
          <tr><td dir='rtl' style='text-align: justify'>
```

and i want get

```
xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx@xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Please provide a test case which you think should match but doesn't.

Comment: Also, regex isn't ideal for getting info from HTML/XML formats.  Perhaps you'd be better off with a parser?

Answer (score 2):

It's the tiny whitespace at the start of your Regex pattern. If you remove it, you can get what you want using mloginName.Groups[1] .

Answer (score 0):

So is there no whitespace/new lines in the web page?